# ESP32 Cam without internet

Tags: esp32

I am newly experimenting with WiFi module ESP32 CAM, and I found that it works "well".

My problems are a high latency, but there are many devices connected to my home network.
I have seen videos and it seems even at 1600x1200 ther can be got over 10fps, but I got no more than 5 on HVGA.

I have created another network (not connected to internet) with an old router Linksys WRT54, and my computers and tablets connect well, getting their own IP and seeing each other, so I assume the network goes well.

But I am not able to get an IP address for the ESP32 CAM. And this module works when connected to my home network.

I am using the standard code from github for "CameraWebServer_Test" for Arduino.

I really do not understand why the ESP32 is not getting an IP address, like the computer (Windows11) or the tablet (android).

I would be grateful if somebody can help me.

Comment: Any way you could plug in an RJ-45 to connect it to the router so it can assign it a real direct IP?  If not you would have to do tons of routing and hardcode some blocks of IPs and maybe lock them in by MAC address or something to make sure its getting the right device.  All this can be fixed with just a cable.

Comment: Also of note, you mentioned "high latency" so this would also address that problem most likely as well.  I know you want to do the wifi, and you can for the devices, but you want the source to be a cable if you can help it.  Just run a test cable on the floor and see if that fixes the issue before you worry about how to hide the cable.

Comment: thank you for your comments, but I am afraid that this is not the issue. Maybe I explained myself wrong. then sorry.

Comment: The ESP32 cam works with a router connected to the internet, and also PC and tablet work in a network without internet. My issue is how to configure the ESP32 cam to get also a router's IP, when that router is not connected to internet. The router works well and provide IP addresses, so why the ESP32 is not getting one?

Comment: I want the ESP32 cam working in a separate network. Joining to the internet means travelling inside my busy network, with those poor results

Comment: Oh wait .. so the router is dishing out the DHCP IP address, and it gives one to the camera?  But if the other devices are not connecting to that router to gain access to the network then maybe that is your issue.  You need a DHCP host that is on that same network as all the devices.   Also when you say router, is this one of those all in one router/switch rigs that come from providers?

Comment: Man I just re-read this, its not about access but just latency?  It might be the wifi router is of older technology and is capping throughput I bet.  Sadly the same answer is the same solution, a cable would fix the throughput, or at the VERY least be a very good test, because if you use a cable and it still lags then you know you have a bottleneck on the CAM somehow.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a cable connection for the cameras. They are ESP32-based and have just WiFi. But I made a couple of tests. When I connect the WAN of this WRT54 to the LAN of my provider's Modem-Router, (with Cable and through Powerline LAN adapters,) I get 54Mbps to Internet through the W-LAN of the WRT54, so this means that the WLAof WRT54 is at least 54Mbps capable. When I connect the cameras to the provider's router, I get 45-58Mbps, so 54Mbps should suffice.

Comment: But that is not the point. I get an IP-Address for the devices (PC, Tablet) connected to the WRT54-WLAN, and I can share files, even this is an isolated system.  On the other hand, when I connect the ESP32 camera to the WRT54, I do not get any IP address, even when I connect the WLAN of the WRT54 to the LAN ports of the provider?s router.   I do not understand why my WRT54 is providing (local) addresses to the PC and tablet but not to the ESP32.   I am missing something, but I do not understand what.   I also tried the WRT54 in both Gateway and Router modes.

Comment: Well I was hoping was an ez fix because this isn't even the right stack for this so I don't know if i can even offer you more advice.  I hope you figure it out.